# Brute force string matching in Scala

Tags: algorithm, scala

I'm new to Scala and for practice I'm trying to write brute-force string matching function that can return a list of indices of matches. The best that I have is pasted below. I would appreciate assitance in making this idiomatic. Also as you'll notice this just prints the indices, whereas I'd prefer a List or Stream.

```
def strMatching(txt: String, pat: String): Unit = {
        val N = txt.length
        val M = pat.length
        for (i <- 1 to N-M) {
            var j = 0
            while (j < M && pat(j) == txt(i+j)) {
                if (j == M-1) print(s"${i+1} ")
                j = j + 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A possible one liner, with the brute force algorithm, could be

```
txt.indices.filter(i => txt.substring(i).startsWith(pat))
```

Comment: even shorter : txt.indices filter (txt.startsWith(pat, _))

Answer (score 1):

```
def strMatch(txt: String, pat: String): List[Int] = {

     var index = 0;
     var indices = List.empty[Int]

     // sliding gives a sliding window of given length
     txt sliding pat.length foreach { x => 
                                      if (pat == x) indices = indices :+ index
                                      index += 1 }

     indices
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To be honest, I'd prefer a solution that doesn't use a var

Comment: It's fine. The above function with `var` is side-effect free, which is what matters.